# Count Of an Element in json array

Tags: android, json

This is my `JSON` array,

```
[{
    "textinput": [{
        "position": 0,
        "dependency": "no",
        "id": 0,
        "label": "single1",
        "Itype": "textinput"
    }, {
        "position": 1,
        "dependency": "no",
        "id": 1,
        "label": "single2",
        "Itype": "textinput"
    }, {
        "position": 2,
        "dependency": "no",
        "id": 2,
        "label": "single3",
        "Itype": "textinput"
    }, {
        "position": 3,
        "dependency": "no",
        "id": 3,
        "label": "single4",
        "Itype": "textinput"
    }, {
        "position": 4,
        "dependency": "no",
        "id": 4,
        "label": "single5",
        "Itype": "textinput"
    }, {
        "position": 5,
        "dependency": "no",
        "id": 5,
        "label": "single6",
        "Itype": "textinput"
    }]
}]
```

I would like to get help in counting the number of `position` in the above array.

Comment: no of count of position is jsonarray.length....

Comment: what exactly you looking for you want to get sum of position??if not then you just need jsonArraylength it give count of your responses.

Comment: not the sum but how many " position" are there in the array @AndroidDeveloper

Comment: then put your whole json. because json never starts with JsonArray Its always starts with root Json Object

Answer (score 1):

You missed out the j there :P

```
try {
     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("Your response");    
     int count = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("textinput").length();
 } catch (JSONException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

String[] array = text.split("position");  //text your reponse json String

int count = array.length-1;  //the number of position